# The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-2

As the title says I'm having issues connecting to my database with my application.

This is the error I am getting

> The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.

And this is the code for it:

```
        public SaleswebEntities() : base("name=SaleswebEntities", "SaleswebEntities")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }
```

And this is my Connection string.

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="SaleswebEntities" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Salesweb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

As fast as I can see I have no typo, might be worth to mention this is a MVC2 application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a DSN?  http://www.connectionstrings.com/dsn/:

Go here:  %windir%\system32\odbcad32.exe and/or C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe to add...

Comment: No, I am not using a DSN

Comment: If I was stuck like this, I'd try something different, such as adding/using a DSN. Best of luck.